# Magento deleted my products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, multistore, csv

I am trying to import a spreadsheet with some products in csv with a standard sku, as alm001-alm002-etc.
I already have some registered products of 001-560, but when I import the new .csv file (beyond 561 to 0610), it deletes the other products of the same early sku (alm)

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! You will need to provide detailed reproduction steps for us to help. For starters maybe a line or two of the CSV. Have you tried this on a plain Magento 1.9CE freshly installed?

Comment: And please tell us in which mode you import it. Do you use Import/Export or Dataflow?